# Proof checking Number theory: prove that $d\nmid a^{2^{n}}+1$.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility, congruences, primitive-roots

Let $a, d, n$ be positive integers with $2<d<2^{n+1}$, prove that $d\nmid a^{2^{n}}+1$.

I've made some preliminary observations: 
I hypothesize that for any $n$, $a^{2^n}+1=2\prod p$ where the $p$s are prime numbers which are all bigger than $2^n+1$.

How should I proceed?

Edit: I've come up with the following proof. Not sure if it is sound.

Suppose to the contrary that for any $2<d<2^{n+1}$, there exists $a$ such that $d\mid a^{2^n}+1$. Then clearly $(a^{2^n},d)=1$ and consequently $(a,d)=1$.

$d\mid a^{2^n}+1$ implies $a^{2^n}\equiv -1 \mod(d)$, and therefore $a^{2^{n+1}}\equiv 1 \mod(d)$. Take $h$ to be the order of $a$, then $h\mid 2^{n+1}$, which means $h$ is a power of $2$. Then consider the fact that $a^h\equiv a^{2^k} \equiv 1$ implies that $(a^h)^2 \equiv a^{2^{k+1}} \equiv 1^2 \equiv 1$ We can keep on doing this until the index is $n$, but here is the contradiction as we said above that $a^{2^n}\equiv -1 \not\equiv 1\mod(d)$. 
Is the proof sound? The problem is that it seems that I haven't made use of the fact that $2<d<2^{n+1}$.

Comment: I think I've made some mistakes - I actually have no proof for that observation. I will edit accordingly

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Show that, if $p$ is an odd prime natural number dividing $a^{2^n}+1$, then $p=2^{n+1}k+1$ for some positive integer $k$.

**Remark on the OP's Attempt:**  You have proven that the order of $a$ modulo $d$ must be exactly $2^{n+1}$.  What does this say about $d$?

Comment: any more hints as to how to proceed?

Comment: Prove that, if $d>2$ divides $a^{2^n}+1$, then it has an odd prime divisor.